# Switching between two storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

Wait! Before you hit the 'possible duplicate of ...' key, please read my description to the end!

In my app I have two storyboard files, one is the initial storyboard that is opened automatically (as set in the project settings Main interface.

The second storyboard I want to open at a specific point when the user taps a specific item in the first storyboard's view.

I've read a couple of tutorials (and other tickets on SO) about using multiple storyboards but all of them seem to make use of a UINavigationController. However in my app I don't use a UINavigationController as the underlying base controller.

What I would like to do is simply instantiate the 2. storyboard from within the first storyboard (or the in app delegate directed by the first storyboard) and then dispose the whole view/controller hierarchy of the first storyboard because it's not needed to be in the background (until the user decides to go back).

I know I can instantiate the second storyboard and get its view controller with:

```
    var s:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: bundle);
    var c:UIViewController = s.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController;
```

But how do I proceed from there on to properly get the 2. storyboard view displayed (and possibly dispose/remove the view of the 1. storyboard)?

Comment: If you don't want anything from the old storyboard at all, set your UIWindow's `rootViewController` property to `c`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment! That seems to work. But is that clean? Am I not leaving something to be cleaned up, e.g. removing views? Simply switching out the rootViewController seems brutal to me.

Comment: If there are no other references to your old storyboard or views, ARC will deallocate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want anything from the old storyboard at all, set your UIWindow's `rootViewController` property to `c`. If there are no other strong references to your old storyboard or views, ARC will deallocate them.

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController = c
```

Comment: This might not always work. For example, when dismissing a `UIAlertView`, the `keyWindow` is the alert view's window, not your app's window.